# Count the number of times appears of each word

Tags: javascript, count, words

How to count the number of times appears of each word in a text introduced by the user? I have this for now:

```js
function print() {
    text1 = texto.value;                                                     
    var sim = /\s+/gi;                                                      
    var word= texto.value.trim().replace(sim, ' ').split(' ').length;   
    var space= texto.value.split(" ").length - 1;                          
    alert("Number of spaces: " + (space) + "\nNumber of words: " + (word));
    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = text.value;
}

countWords(document.getElementById("IDTextAreal").value());
```

If the user introduces the string "Hello my name is Hello" the script show:

```
Hello: 2, my: 1, name: 1, is: 1.
```

Comment: Did  you search ? There are many similar question here. And what you ask isn't clear.

Comment: I see some similar questions but I don't understand how works. Can you explain where is my error and how can implemate in the script? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to make a two dimensional array.  The first dimension will contain the word - and the second will contain the count.  Then, as you iterate through the words that were entered, you will check if it exists in your array.  If it does, you will increment the second dimension by one.  If not, you will push [word][1] to your array.  Next, you can iterate through the array to get the words and their respective counts for display.

Answer (score 0):

In inspect element see the result in console area

```
 $(function() {
            var str = "Hello my name is Hello";
            var strArray = str.split(" ");
            var result = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
                var re = new RegExp(strArray[i], 'g');
                var n = str.match(re).length;
                result[strArray[i]] = n;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
```

Comment: No its in javaScript . Because your question was in javaScript